# Why will my pictures not go through my if statements

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make it so that every time that I click on the button that I created it cycles through the photos. Right now it won't do anything that I want

I think that a for loop would be the best way to go about this but I don't know what I am doing

```js
var images = ["img/profile.jpg", "img/mountain.jpg", "img/sanfran.jpg"];


function loadPage() {
  document.getElementById("pictures").src = images[0];
}

function nextImage() {
  if (document.getElementById("pictures").src = images[0]) {
    document.getElementById("pictures").src = images[1];
  } else if (document.getElementById("pictures").src = images[1]) {
    document.getElementById("pictures").src = images[2];
  } else(document.getElementById("pictures").src = images[2]) {
    document.getElementById("pictures").src = images[0];
  }
}
```

```html
<body onclick="loadPage()">
  <div id="maincontent">
    <div>
      <img id="pictures">
    </div>
    <div id="paragraph">
      <button class="button" onclick="nextImage()">Switch Images</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You need `==` in the if statements to compare two values. `=` is for setting a value

Comment: I think, you should learn the basic structures for `if`, `for`, `while` etc before going deeper.

Comment: `<body onclick="loadPage()">` Won't this always trigger the `loadPage` function on the button click, endlessly setting the first picture ?

Answer (score 2):

While Jet is on the right track. It will stop working after the last image, as `index` will be out of bounds.

**EDIT** Jet has updated their code, and the way of keeping `index` in bounds is quite elegant.

See the below example:

```html
<body>
  <div id="maincontent">
    <div>
       <img id="pictures">
    </div>
    <div id="paragraph">
      <button class="button" onclick="nextImage()">Switch Images</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script>
    var images = [
      "https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.png?text=1",
      "https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.png?text=2",
      "https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.png?text=3"
    ];

    let currentImage = -1;

    function nextImage() {
      currentImage++; // Add 1 to the currentImage variable
      if (currentImage === images.length) {
        currentImage = 0; // If we've reached the last image, go to the first image
      }

      document.getElementById("pictures").src = images[currentImage]; // Set the src image to the current image in our images array
    }

    nextImage();
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: So I am getting an error that says I cannot have a value of null where it is supposed to be setting the src image to the current image

Comment: If you click 'Run code snippet', you can see that this runs. Compare it with yours. Also, paste the entire error.

Comment: script.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null
    at nextImage (script.js:12)
    at script.js:15

Comment: It cannot find an element with id ```pictures```. ```<img id="pictures">``` is missing on the page, or the ```id``` is different.

Comment: Spelling error actually it did work thanks a ton

Comment: No problem. Don't forget marking mine or Jets answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Bascially i cycle through the names of images stored in the array. i used the modulo (%) to ensure that i wont go out of bound of the array

```
<body>
<div id="maincontent">
  <div>
     <img src="img/profile.jpg" id="pictures">
  </div>
  <div id="paragraph">
    <button class="button" onclick="nextImage()">Switch Images</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var index = 1;
  var images = ["img/profile.jpg", "img/mountain.jpg", "img/sanfran.jpg"];

  function nextImage(){

    document.getElementById('pictures').src = images[index%3];
    index++;
  }

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Since it would appear the OP is a beginner, you might want to add an explanation of how this works

Comment: @JetHerngChion What is purpose of `0%3`?

Comment: @MaheerAli sorry for the typo, i have edited it

Answer (score 1):

`==` is used for conditions, and `=` is used for assignment. However, I would advise using a `switch` in this case instead of an `if` statement as below:

```
<body onclick="loadPage()">
    <div id="maincontent">
        <div>
            <img id="pictures">
       </div>
        <div id="paragraph">
            <button class="button" onclick="nextImage()">Switch Images</button>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <script>
        let images = ["img/profile.jpg", "img/mountain.jpg", "img/sanfran.jpg"];
        let src = document.getElementById("pictures").src

        function loadPage() {
            src = images[0];
        }

        function nextImage() {

            switch (document.getElementById("pictures").src) {
                case images[0]:
                   src = images[1];
                   break
                case images[1]:
                    src = images[2];
                    break
                case images[2]:
                    src = images[0];
                    break
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

**EDIT: It seems others have come up with an even more efficient way to do this, but I'll leave it here as a reference to an alternative.**

Answer (score 1):

```js
var images = ["https://via.placeholder.com/150", "https://via.placeholder.com/500",]; 
var imageElement = document.getElementById("pictures");
function loadPage() {
  imageElement.src = images[0];
 }

 function nextImage() {
  if(imageElement.src == images[0])
   imageElement.src = images[1];
  else if (imageElement.src == images[1])
   imageElement.src = images[2];
   else if (imageElement.src == images[2]) 
   imageElement.src = images[0];
 }
```

```html
<body onclick="loadPage()">
<div id="maincontent">
  <div>
     <img id="pictures">
  </div>
  <div id="paragraph">
    <button class="button" onclick="nextImage()">Switch Images</button>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

The issue was simple, inside IF conditions use == 
== is for comparison, = is for assignment

*P.S instead of calling document.getElementById repeadetly to get the same element, you can also store the element's reference once in a variable and use it, to increase performance*